# How to form str.decode line?

Tags: python

With this line

```
str(hex(int(207))).decode('cp1251',errors='strict')
```

I get

```
'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

What is the correct way to format the line?

Comment: What result do you want ? `decode` is for a byte string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) method you want belongs to `Bytes` and `BytesArray` objects. So you need to convert your hex string to `Bytes` (or `BytesArray` I guess).

**Solution**

For this, you can use the `fromhex` method to convert the hex string. But it may require some formatting beforehand to exclude the `'0x'` part of the string. You may be better off therefore using Python's `format`, or f-strings, instead of `hex`.

Here is an example.

```
integer = 207
hexstring = f'{integer:x}'
hexbytes = bytes.fromhex(hexstring)
decoded = hexbytes.decode('cp1251',errors='strict')
```

Of course, you can combine the above into your original one-liner if you wish.